# Promise factories not working in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I need to perform some async tasks in Nodejs. In this case, I need to iterate throw al levels of a JSON. For that reason, I need to "iterate" syncronusly that object but in order.

I'm doing tests with this code which is a simple example adapted from [this site](http://www.datchley.name/promise-patterns-anti-patterns/)

```
var fnlist = [ doFirstThing, doSecondThing, doThirdThing, lastThing];

// Promise returning functions to execute
function doFirstThing(){ return Promise.resolve(1); }  
function doSecondThing(res){ return Promise.resolve(res + 1); }  
function doThirdThing(res){ return Promise.resolve(res + 2); }  
function lastThing(res){ console.log("result:", res); }

// Execute a list of Promise return functions in series
function pseries(req,json,list) {  
  var p = Promise.resolve();
    return doFirstThing()
    .then((value) => {
        console.log('value');
        console.log(value);
        return doSecondThing(value).then((value2) => {
            console.log('value2');
            console.log(value2);
        });
    });
}

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var thisArray = json[0].array;

    for(var i = 0;i < thisArray.length; i++){
        pseries(req,json,fnlist);
    }
});
```

Console output is:

```
1
value
1
value
1
value2
2
value2
2
value2
2
```

And is not still valid because I would need to have this kind of flow:

```
value
1
value2
2
value
1
value2
2
value
1
value2
2
```

I know I need to use **promises factories** in order to don't execute them as soon as they are created, but seems to not be working now. I know **I can't use .all** because I need to use some data from one promise in the next one.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using promises for this?  Ther are no actual async operations shown here so using promises just makes things more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have started multiple independent promise chains in your `for` loop (each call to `pseries()` is a separate promise chain).  As such, you cannot control the sequencing of the separate promise chains.  If you want to control one chain vs. another, then you will have to link them (e.g. chain them together) so the ordering is explicit rather than left to chance.

The output you see is not surprising because the first thing your `for` loop does is register a bunch of `.then()` handlers.  Because the promises are already resolved for those, the `.then()` handlers are all queued to run as soon as your `for` loop is done **(`.then()` handlers are ALWAYS queued to run asynchronously)**.  The `for` loop finishes and then the first crop of `.then()` handlers all run.  The process of running them schedules three more `.then()` handlers.  Those are then queued and they run when the first crop of `.then()` handlers is all done.  While I explained the likely logic for why you get the order you see, this is not guaranteed.   These are async operations and the only thing you know is that they complete some uncertain time in the future.  If you want explicit order, you have to force that through explicit synchronization of your promises.

You can sequence an iteration through an array in a known order like this using a fairly common design pattern with `array.reduce()`:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var thisArray = json[0].array;

    thisArray.reduce(function(p, item) {
        return p.then(function() {
            return pseries(req,json,fnlist);
        });
    }, Promise.resolve()).then(function(result) {
        // all done here
    }, function(err) {
        // error here
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00. The original example I posted also uses array_reduce but checking the doc it sums all elems. from an array. I want to store in database so I don't want to sum values.

Comment: @Joss - `.reduce()` is just one way to iterate through an array accumulating some value.  Here's it uses that feature to chain a promise to solve your problem.  There is no sum of values here.  Please read and understand the code.  If what you're trying to do is sequence your async operations on the array, that's what this code does.  FYI, there's no `.reduce()` anywhere in your question so I don't know where you already posted that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to chain all your promise using a foreach:

```
var sequence = Promise.resolve();

// Loop through our chapter urls
story.chapterUrls.forEach(function(chapterUrl) {
  // Add these actions to the end of the sequence
  sequence = sequence.then(function() {
    return getJSON(chapterUrl);
  }).then(function(chapter) {
    addHtmlToPage(chapter.html);
  });
});
```

for more complex combination, check this page:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-parallelism-sequencing